# Windows 7 Line In Delay Issue

Tags: audio, drivers, latency

I'm running Windows 7 Pro 32-bit on my Dell Latitude 2100 netbook and I'm having an issue with the line in device/driver/functionality.

The device & driver are stock:

- Driver Date: 7/13/2009
- Driver Version: 6.1.7600.16385

My setup is bass guitar running through a 12' long instrument cable (1/4") with a 1/4" female to 1/8" male adapter into the line in port on the computer. Then the 15' long headphones/line out cable goes into a standard set of powered speakers.

I'm almost sure that the manufacturer of the on-board sound card is RealTek.

The problem is that there is latency (when monitoring input) between the source and the speakers.

How do I get rid of this latency?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Rather than guessing whether or not this (or any other) is the appropriate site, why not take a few moments to read the FAQ and find out for sure?

Comment: @John G - if your question isn't rhetorical, the answer is that i was frustrated at the time and i'm just that lazy in general

Comment: @John G - also, since you seem to know & respect the law of the stackexchange land, what are your thoughts on me reposting this same question/issue on both http://guitars.stackexchange.com/ and http://audio.stackexchange.com/ in addition to superuser?

Comment: nvm guitars site.... i reposted on audio.stackexchange.com  ( http://audio.stackexchange.com/questions/856/windows-7-line-in-latency-issue ) - separate audience & suitable arena